# How many tangents does a fixed curve have to the curves in a pencil?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective surface over $\mathbb{C}$ equipped with ample line bundles $L, L'$. Consider a fixed smooth curve $P$ in the linear system $|L|$, and consider a pencil $Q_\lambda$ of curves in $|L'|$.

Assume that $P$ does not intersect any critical point of $Q_\lambda$ (i.e. the singular point of a singular fiber), and does not pass through the base locus of $Q_\lambda$. Under these assumptions, I'm looking for a formula that enumerates the number of tangent points between $P$ and curves in $Q_\lambda$; I expect there should be one involving the degrees of the line bundles $L, L'$ as well as the canonical bundle of $X$.

This is probably an easy exercise somewhere, but any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at the chapter on Singular Elements of Linear Series in Eisenbud-Harris' *3264 and All That*. The tangency condition sounds like the sort of thing that can be encoded using bundles of principle parts, which are discussed in that chapter at length.

Comment: This chapter is at the very top of my reading list - thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pencil $Q_\lambda$ defines a rational map $X \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ which restricts to a regular morphism
$$
P \to \mathbb{P}^1
$$
of degree $P \cdot Q_\lambda = \mathcal{L} \cdot \mathcal{L'}$. The points of tangency become the ramification points for this covering, so you can count them via the Hurwitz formula.